# Parsing value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scripting

I'm trying to figure out why my code is not triggering past a certain point. In the below code the alert for Luhn is displaying fine but it appears to not progress past that. So it appears i am successfully passing the number from the onclick method but the function is not running because i'm not getting a true or false alert based on the rule set.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validate(Luhn) {
            alert(Luhn);
            var LuhnDigit = parseInt(Luhn.substring(Luhn.length - 1, Luhn.length));
            var LuhnLess = Luhn.substring(0, Luhn.length - 1);
            if (Calculate(LuhnLess) == parseInt(LuhnDigit)) {
                alert("True");
                return true;
            }
            alert("False");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="form" id='fv'>
        <input type="button" onclick="Validate('4111111111111111')" value="Call function">

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You know you're not an experienced Javascript programmer when... you name your functions with a capitalized word :)

Comment: Sprung :) We all start somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

The statement after `return` wont execute and execution control is immediately transferred to calling function. Put `alert` before `return` statement. You can read more about return [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
if (Calculate(LuhnLess)==parseInt(LuhnDigit))
{
    alert("True");
    return true;

}   

alert("False");
return false;
```